# select all that contains values from another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to get all rows from Table A where Table A.FID contains text from Table B.primaryID.

Table A

```
| primaryID |      FID      |
|     1     | Apple (5005)  |
|     2     | Banana (5005) |
|     3     | Apple (2250)  |
|     4     | Banana (1100) |
```

Table B

```
| primaryID | Etc |
|    5005   | abc |
|    1100   | abc |
```

The result query should give me Table A rows 1, 2 and 4.

I started out with the query below but did not generate the result i need.

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE [TableA].[FID] 
 LIKE  “*” & [TableB].[primaryID] & ”*”;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work in MS Access:

```
 SELECT ta.*
 FROM TableA as ta INNER JOIN
      TableB as tb
      ON ta.fid LIKE "*" & tb.primaryId & "*";
```

You need to have both tables in the `FROM` clause.

EDIT:

Actually, a formulation using `exists` may be closer to what you were thinking:

```
select *
from TableA
where exists (select 1
              from TableB
              where [TableA].[FID] LIKE "*" & [TableB].[primaryID] & "*"
             );
```